# unable to add gif to web page with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a web page with a link called "Download". When user press that link, I'm using javascript to add a gif animation so that user knows that the system is busy. Here is the code:

```
function submit_form()
{
  var nfy = document.getElementById('nfy_area');
  var img = document.createElement( 'img' );
  img.setAttribute('src', 'images/wait24trans.gif');
  nfy.innerHTML = "This will take a few minutes. Please be patient...";
  nfy.appendChild( img );
  document.forms["download_form"].submit();
}
```

However, this only works for Opera. For Chrome, nothing is displayed. For Firefox, a broken image is displayed.

Why?

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you.  The actual image insertion seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/bkHAY/ (tested in ff, safari, chrome, and opera).  Perhaps something is interfering with the call to your submit_form function...? Maybe try adding some breakpoints in chrome and ff and see what's firing and when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The target of the submit action is another page. So presumably both FF and Chrome detect this and stops loading anything else on the current page. I put in a delay before submitting the form and now it works fine.

Commendably, Opera works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out broken images on firefox to see where does it search for image to fix the src.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the HTML5 spec is likely to require that the `submit()` call there imply a `stop()` call.